# Vim Indentation Using ">"

Tags: vim

I'm using vim under Mac OS 10.7 Terminal.

My .vimrc already specify the tabstop to be 4. However, if I use shift to select multiple lines and then using ">" to indent, it will give me a indention of 8 spaces instead of 4. How can I correct that to be 4?

Part of my .vimrc:

```
set cindent
set autoindent
set tabstop=4
```

Comment: Did you try also to set sw=4 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `shiftwidth` variable controls the indentation:

```
set shiftwidth=4
```

Comment: also ensure that `expandtab` is set if you want spaces.

Comment: For more information on the subject check out Drew Neil's vimcast on tabs and spaces: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/

Answer (score 2):

```
set shiftwidth=4
```

They're different things: `tabstop` says how many spaces wide to use when displaying a tab character, `shiftwidth` is for indentation.